# register_sidebar notice

Tags: register-sidebar, notices

I have updated my site manually, now I get below mentioned notice in the front and backend:

> Notice: register_sidebar was called incorrectly. No id was set in the
> arguments array for the "Main Sidebar" sidebar. Defaulting to
> "sidebar-1". Manually set the id to "sidebar-1" to silence this notice
> and keep existing sidebar content. Please see Debugging in WordPress
> for more information. (This message was added in version 4.2.0.)

How to fix this?

Answer (score 14):

1. Find file where is `register_sidebar` ( must be on theme folder or plugins )
2. add ID to sidebar

   ```
   register_sidebar( array(
      'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'theme-slug' ),

      'id' => 'change_me',  // Add only this line

      'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on all posts and pages.', 'theme-slug' ),
      'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
      'after_widget'  => '</li>',
      'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
      'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
   ```

Or you can just disable notification in `wp-config.php`

edit `WP_DEBUG` to false

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a very old theme. You'll have to search the `functions.php` file for `register_sidebar` and make sure the `$args` follow the format [mentioned in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar).